# Laravel 8 wherePivot() with dynamic parameter

Tags: laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-8

I need to filter some models according many to many relation so I would like to use wherePivot() filter. But it seems it is impossible to send dynamic param to belongsToMany relation. Is it possible or not? I have something like this:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function customer($customer_id)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'event_customers', 'event_id', 'customer_id')
        ->wherePivot('customer_id', $customer_id);
}
```

How can I call it if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to have a scoped Query inside your model where you can receive a parameter and then using that scope you can retrieve this many-to-many relation data.

So, it would be something like this:

> Model:

```
public function scopeFilter($customer_id) {
   return $this->customer()->wherePivot('customer_id', $customer_id);
}
```

> Controller:

```
public function index() {
   //.. Rest of Logic
   Model::filter($customerId);
   //.. Rest of Logic
}
```

This may need some modifications according to your need. But, I hope it helps.

Comment: I solved it by scopeCustomer($id). but this looks interesting. I will try it if I will have a time.

Comment: Yes, basically it's the same. You can name it anything like you did in your case, scopeCustomer and then use Model::customer() to pass the value.